# send whatsapp message using php

Tags: php, android, html, whatsapp

**hi.
i want to send whatsapp message using php. i run this code**

```html
<?php
require_once 'Chat-API-master/src/whatsprot.class.php';
$username = "6285648145xxx";
$nickname = "ardi";
$password = "password"; // The one we got registering the number
$debug = true;

// Create a instance of WhastPort.
$w = new WhatsProt($username, $nickname, $debug);

$w->connect(); // Connect to WhatsApp network
$w->loginWithPassword($password); // logging in with the password we got!

$target = '62811304xxxx'; // The number of the person you are sending the message
$message = 'Hi! :) this is a test message';

$w->sendMessage($target , $message);
?>
```

**But i have result this code at my browser**

```html
tx  <stream:features></stream:features>

tx  <auth user="6285648145xxx" mechanism="WAUTH-2"></auth>

rx  <from s.whatsapp.net=""></from>

rx  <stream:features></stream:features>

rx  <challenge>376a507c7e915642d85255fe96cb1d101fa23819</challenge>

tx  <response>200e09fa50b7c6a3fa3416878f1e165e8d7670f054ddeaa1c77278a5f8e5b881f4f9f75dce809f42cbdcf17931db8c15641399488b90e9cb74e87de94560802f98bb028af9b5967403fb278c28e06c</response>


Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\waonline\Chat-API-master\src\whatsprot.class.php on line 2609
```

what's wrong?? please give me sollution. thanks

Comment: hide password, if its correct

Comment: Well you have exceeded the default maximum runtime of a PHP script allowed by your config. That can be fixed, but I cannot see from the code you actually show why 30 seconds is not enough time to run that script. So is this ALL the code in your script?

Comment: Why the [tag:android] tag?

Comment: ok. i will check my code again. thanks. maybe you have other code for send the whatsapp message using php ?

Answer (score 1):

### Use the official "Click to Chat" API

The first possible way was thorugh a URL procedure sending the user to:

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=XXYYYYYYYY
```

(where `XX` is the country code and `YYYYYYYY` is the number)

Nowadays the API comes in a shorter format and allows including the text message.

```
https://wa.me/XXYYYYYYYY/?text=urlencodedtext
```

(where `URL-encodedtext` is the URL-encoded pre-filled message)

It's also possible to just assign a message to be sent but with no user specified, letting the user to later choose whom to send it to, being able to send it to many people at once, with this method:

```
https://wa.me/?text=urlencodedtext
```

You can see all the official current information in here
https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
set_time_limit(120);
```

Your script takes too long to execute

Comment: Except that some hosting companies will disable this ability

Comment: where i put the code 'set_time_limit(120);'  and maybe you have other code for send message using php?

Answer (score 0):

[The official documentation says to use their wa.me URL](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/), so let's just check it out: [http://wa.me/?text=mytest](https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?text=mytest&type=custom_url&app_absent=0).  What do you see?  Do you see an error page?  This is what I see:

> We couldn't find the page you were looking for
>
> Looks like you're looking for a page that doesn't exist. Or a page we might have just deleted. Either way, go back or be sure to check the url, your spelling and try again.

So, in short, *DO NOT use the wa.me URL*.  Use the `api.whatsapp.com` URL, like one of these:

> https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=YourShareTextHere
>
> https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=YourShareTextHere&phone=123

These both work perfectly for me!

If you are interested in watching a project that keeps track of these URLs, then check us out!: https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls#whatsapp

[image: Social Share URLs]